# Entrez epost + elink returns results out of order with Biopython

Tags: python, bioinformatics, biopython, ncbi

I ran into this today and wanted to toss it out there.  It appears that using the the Biopython interface to Entrez at NCBI, it's not possible to get results back (at least from elink) in the correct (same as input) order.  Please see the code below for an example.  I have thousands of GIs for which I need to get taxonomy information, and querying them individually is painfully slow due to NCBI restrictions.

```
from Bio import Entrez
Entrez.email = "my@email.com"
ids = ["148908191", "297793721", "48525513", "507118461"]
search_results = Entrez.read(Entrez.epost("protein", id=','.join(ids)))
webenv = search_results["WebEnv"]
query_key = search_results["QueryKey"] 
print Entrez.read(Entrez.elink(webenv=webenv, 
                         query_key=query_key,
                         dbfrom="protein",
                         db="taxonomy"))

print "-------"

for i in ids:
    search_results = Entrez.read(Entrez.epost("protein", id=i))
    webenv = search_results["WebEnv"]
    query_key = search_results["QueryKey"] 
    print Entrez.read(Entrez.elink(webenv=webenv, 
                         query_key=query_key,
                         dbfrom="protein",
                         db="taxonomy"))
```

Results:

```
[{u'LinkSetDb': [{u'DbTo': 'taxonomy', u'Link': [{u'Id': '211604'}, {u'Id': '81972'}, {u'Id': '32630'}, {u'Id': '3332'}], u'LinkName': 'protein_taxonomy'}], u'DbFrom': 'protein', u'IdList': ['148908191', '297793721', '48525513', '507118461'], u'LinkSetDbHistory': [], u'ERROR': []}]
-------
[{u'LinkSetDb': [{u'DbTo': 'taxonomy', u'Link': [{u'Id': '3332'}], u'LinkName': 'protein_taxonomy'}], u'DbFrom': 'protein', u'IdList': ['148908191'], u'LinkSetDbHistory': [], u'ERROR': []}]
[{u'LinkSetDb': [{u'DbTo': 'taxonomy', u'Link': [{u'Id': '81972'}], u'LinkName': 'protein_taxonomy'}], u'DbFrom': 'protein', u'IdList': ['297793721'], u'LinkSetDbHistory': [], u'ERROR': []}]
[{u'LinkSetDb': [{u'DbTo': 'taxonomy', u'Link': [{u'Id': '211604'}], u'LinkName': 'protein_taxonomy'}], u'DbFrom': 'protein', u'IdList': ['48525513'], u'LinkSetDbHistory': [], u'ERROR': []}]
[{u'LinkSetDb': [{u'DbTo': 'taxonomy', u'Link': [{u'Id': '32630'}], u'LinkName': 'protein_taxonomy'}], u'DbFrom': 'protein', u'IdList': ['507118461'], u'LinkSetDbHistory': [], u'ERROR': []}]
```

The elink documentation (http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK25499/) at NCBI says this should be possible, 
but only by passing multiple 'id=', but this doesn't appear possible with the Biopython epost interface.  Has anyone else seen this or am I missing something obvious.

Thanks!

Comment: Duplicate post on biostars https://www.biostars.org/p/112225/

Answer (score 1):

```
from Bio import Entrez


Entrez.email = "my@email.com"
ids = ["148908191", "297793721", "48525513", "507118461"]
search_results = Entrez.read(Entrez.epost("protein", id=','.join(ids)))

xml = Entrez.efetch("protein",
                    query_key=search_results["QueryKey"],
                    WebEnv=search_results["WebEnv"],
                    rettype="gp",
                    retmode="xml")

for record in Entrez.read(xml):
    print [x[3:] for x in record["GBSeq_other-seqids"] if x.startswith("gi")]
    gb_quals = record["GBSeq_feature-table"][0]["GBFeature_quals"]
    for qualifier in gb_quals:
        if qualifier["GBQualifier_name"] == "db_xref":
            print qualifier["GBQualifier_value"]

     # Or with list comprehension
     # print [q["GBQualifier_value"] for q in
     #        record["GBSeq_feature-table"][0]["GBFeature_quals"] if
     #        q["GBQualifier_name"] == "db_xref"]


xml.close()
```

I `efetch` the Query, and then parse-like the xml after read it with `Entrez.read()`. This is where things turn messy, and you have to dive the xml-dict-list. I guess there's a way to extract the "GBFeature_quals" where "GBQualifier_name" is "db_xref" nicer than mine... but this works (by now). Output:

```
['148908191']
taxon:3332

['297793721']
taxon:81972

['48525513']
taxon:211604

['507118461']
taxon:32630
```

Comment: minor point, but rettype="gp" should be "gb", I guess.  Thanks!  I was doing this earlier, but wanted to *simplify* my code a bit through elink.

Comment: I always look at the "rettypes" available at http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK25499/table/chapter4.chapter4_table1/?report=objectonly . It's `gp` :).

Comment: Oh, and the "scrambling" of the id/taxon order is at NCBI level, before the generation of the XML. Biopython can do little with that.